# Is it possible for customs to be transmitted from the mother?

Tags: halacha, minhag, baal-teshuva

Suppose someone is becoming more religious and he doesn't know his father's minhagim. Should he follow the minhagim of his mother and her family or of the rabbi who taught him and helped him become more religious?

Comment: @Double AA Those threads don't address what happens if only the mother has a known custom...

Comment: @DoubleAA I changed the question

Comment: It sounds very like http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10584 now

Comment: @msh210 Again, none of these questions address the question of what if only the mother's minhagim are known (since customs are usually transmitted through the father)